# How to use Local Group Policy on Windows 7 to allow or block URL’s for chrome and firefox?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy

I am a regular user not system admin. I need the help to use local group policy to allow to open one domain. For example, www.xxxx.com to open on the chrome or firefox (third-party browser), and make this domain name as a home page.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome can be configured using GPO, Google offers a template for that: http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip

The default home page for Firefox cannot be set directly with Group Policy (except maybe with help of the addon https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/gpo-for-firefox/, but not officially supported by Mozilla). Usually this is done by creating an autoconfig file in the same directory as the file firefox.exe (in most cases named mozilla.cfg), and activating that by creating another file (often named autostart.js) in the subdirectory defaults/pref. Another (and probably the easiest) option is to use the CCK2 wizard by Mike Kaply, and use GPO to deploy a Firefox which has the output of that wizard integrated.